# Find first empty cell in a column

Tags: excel, vba

Hello i'm very new to Excel , but I have made a simple Invoice system, and I need a button that will register the contents of the Invoice in my "Invoice History" spreadsheet, but for that i would need to find where in my spreadsheet should i paste the values, AKA first empty cell of Column A.

Comment: @simoco i have tried recording a macro and holding ctrl+down arrow, but that didn't work, it always chooses the same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you don't have any empty rows in-between your data that you want to fill, you can find the last empty cell of a data range by doing something similar to the following code.

```
Sub FirstEmptyCell()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lCell As Range
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Set lCell = ws.Cells(ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)
    MsgBox "The first empty cell in column A is " & lCell.Address
End Sub
```

This returns the address of the last empty cell in a `MsgBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **array formula**

```
=SMALL(IF(A:A="",ROW(A:A)),1)
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.